# Stored procedure error OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine [procedurename] is not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am using the ColdFusion code to call a stored procedure:

```
<cffunction access="public" name="create" output="FALSE" returntype="numeric" hint="This function inserts a single bk_faqs record into the database." > 
        <cfargument name="faqQuestion" type="string" required="TRUE" default="" />
        <cfargument name="faqAnswer" required="TRUE" default="" />

        <cfset var faqID = "" />
        <cfset var results = "" />

        <cfstoredproc procedure="usp_bk_faqs_insert" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
            <cfprocparam type="OUT" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" variable="faqID" dbvarname="_faqID"  />
            <cfprocparam type="IN" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="faqQuestion" dbvarname="_faqQuestion" value="#arguments.faqQuestion#" maxlength="255"  />
            <cfprocparam type="IN" cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" variable="faqAnswer" dbvarname="_faqAnswer" value="#arguments.faqAnswer#"  />

            <cfprocresult name="results"  />
        </cfstoredproc>

        <cfset results = faqID />


        <cfreturn results />
    </cffunction>
```

With the MySQL 5 jar, which I downloaded from the MySQL site, and ColdFusion 11, I started getting the error below. While in ColdFusion 10, it is working property.

> **Error Executing Database Query.**
>
> OUT or INOUT argument 1 for routine bakeryshop.usp_bk_faqs_insert is
>   not a variable or NEW pseudo-variable in BEFORE trigger
>
> The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/project1/cw4/admin/cfc/dao/dynamic/bk_faqs.cfc: line 112

Comment: Given that you have a procresult tag, what is the purpose of the procparam type = out tag?

Comment: give me back the ID

Comment: Why not simply include the ID in the results?

Comment: where actually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of bug reports on that error, such as [this one](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69206). Sounds like it is probably a driver issue in this case. You could try a different version, but based on the age and number of bug reports, and the fact that 5.1.39 and 5.1.41 have the same issue, it does not bode well...

Personally, I would get rid of the OUT parameter altogether and just return the ID via a SELECT. Then capture the results with `cfprocresult`, as suggested in the comments. Assuming you want to return the generated ID from an INSERT statement, the SQL would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `yourProcedureName`( ... IN parameters here ...)
BEGIN

    --- your INSERT statement here 

    -- Return newly generated ID  
    SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() AS FaqID
END
```

Comment: Thanks, It works but if we opt out the OUT and INOUT too

Comment: Did quite not follow that :) If you mean the same problem exists with INOUT variables, that would make sense.

Comment: Yes, that is not surprising since it is (essentially) an `out` parameter too. BTW, just to reiterate - simply removing the `<cfprocparam type="out"...>` tag from the code will NOT work.  The `out` parameter must be removed from the procedure definition.  Otherwise, the CF code will throw an error because that parameter is missing.

Comment: Yes, That is true and i had done that, it was a messy work but atleast done, and i think this is not an issue with ACF but with MYSQL driver, I may be wrong, not  sure

Answer (score 2):

This is not a ColdFusion issue.  This seems to be MySQL issue.  Check if your stored procedure has a the out variable faqID.  The stored procedure should have

**`SELECT @faqID;`** after the insert statement, or something similar returning **faqID**

Comment: True, it is a MySQL issue. (BTW, including a link to the bug report which explains the fix would be great.). Unfortunately the suggested "fix" is not possible when a procedure is invoked with cfstoredproc. The invocation is handled behind the scenes and cannot be altered. Given that, I would suggest dropping the OUT variable and returning any data via a regular resultset instead. You could even return multiple resultsets if needed.

Comment: SELECT @faqID; after the insert statement in the actual stored procedure is the solution. <cfstoredproc> simply calls the stored procedure.  The change has to be in the stored procedure.

And yes, dropping the out statement would be another solution; i.e. removing this line:

            <cfprocparam type="OUT" cfsqltype="CF_SQL_INTEGER" variable="faqID" dbvarname="_faqID"  />

I was just making a point that it is not a ColdFusion issue and changing the stored procedure will yield the expected result.

Comment: Hm... maybe I misunderstood. Are you saying adding `SELECT @faqID;` *inside* the stored procedure will make the OUT variable work? (Edit) Never mind. Our comment edits collided. Let me give that a whirl.

Comment: It worked from Workbench, but same error when invoked from CF. Maybe a jdbc driver issue?

Comment: Yes.  Very highly possible it's a driver issue.  Here you go. Solution to the  driver issue: http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2015/5/18/ColdFusion-11--MySQL-no-Suitable-Driver

**Another useful link:**
http://www.greenvalleyconsulting.org/2014/12/22/howto-add-mysql-community-coldfusion-11/

Comment: (Edit) I actually tested with mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar (really thought it would work). The 6.x dev series did not even load. Was thinking of trying jtds too for grins. (Edit) Though ultimately I would probably just drop the `out` param and go with a resulset instead.  Thanks for all the good info.

Comment: Hmm... For some reason it worked for me.  I will need to see what's going on.  But yeah, I agree with you to drop the **in** and **out** types from **<cfprocparam >** tag and remove the out parameters completely.  It will be easy to maintain in the future; unless Adobe decides to change that behaviour in the future and adds strict rules for us to add **in** and **out** types.  Keeping my fingers crossed that doesn't happen.

Comment: RE: *drop the in and out types from <cfprocparam >* Just to clarify, I do not mean remove the `type` declarations :-). I am saying do not even use *output* parameters in the MySQL procedure. If you need to return data, just use a regular resultset.

Comment: Sorry for late reply @Leigh.  By default the vale for "type" attribute is "in". So if you remove all output parameters and keep only IN parameters, you don't have to specify "type" attribute.  But am in favour of what you said, keep the "type" attribute for IN parameters.

Comment: Did you ever figure out why it seemed to work in your environment? Was it just a false positive or might you be using a different driver, like the ones for enterprise MySQL?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get chance to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Willy,

Instead of going through all that, I highly recommend dropping the type attribute from your  and get rid of the out parameter completely. By default the type for  is IN. Change your procedure call like below and it should work:

```
<cfset var faqID = "" />
<cfset var results = "" />

<cfstoredproc procedure="usp_bk_faqs_insert" datasource="#variables.datasource#">
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="CF_SQL_VARCHAR" variable="faqQuestion" dbvarname="_faqQuestion" value="#arguments.faqQuestion#" maxlength="255"  />
    <cfprocparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_longvarchar" variable="faqAnswer" dbvarname="_faqAnswer" value="#arguments.faqAnswer#"  />

    <cfprocresult name="results"  />
</cfstoredproc>

<cfset results = faqID />


<cfreturn results />
```

Comment: Thanks @Nikhil. I will keep this in mind designing future spx but as of now i went with Leigh comment to modify all my SPX, it was a hefty task but now i had done it all.

Comment: @NikhilDevre - No, you cannot just omit the `<cfprocparam type="out"...>`. As long as it is defined in the proc signature, omitting it will cause the call to throw an error, because the db does not receive all of the required parameters.

Comment: @Leigh I was not suggesting to modify the stored procedure.  I was recommending only changing how Willy calls the stored procedure from ColdFusion.  So don't know why minus points there.  Anyway, since Willy has already updated his stored procedure, my recommendation will not work.

Comment: That's fine @Willy.  By the way that suggestion was initially made by me. If you look the discussion between Leigh and I in my previous answer where I asked to use SELECT @faqID; after the insert statement.

Comment: @NikhilDevre - I understand and am saying that will not work. Since the procedure signature includes an `out` parameter, you can't just omit the `<cfprocparam type="out"...>` or the call will fail with an error about missing parameters. As far `SELECT @faqID;` that did not seem to work either under CF11.